# Gradle build without tests

Tags: java, gradle, testing

I want to execute `gradle build` without executing the unit tests. I tried:

```bash
gradle -Dskip.tests build
```

That doesn't seem to do anything. Is there some other command I could use?

Comment: Maybe this helps you [Gradle Buil without tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779768/how-can-i-not-include-a-build-task-when-i-include-a-project-in-my-settings-gradl/24138470#24138470)

Comment: `-DskipTests` is for Maven

Comment: I understand it can be helpful sometimes, but Gradle has easy to enable test concurrency. Maybe shaving 1-2 seconds is not the best thing, so making sure we spend less time running them could allow us to always run tests and not pay for the cost or pay little.

Answer (score 1610, accepted):

You should use the `-x` command line argument which excludes any task.

Try:

```
gradle build -x test
```

**Update:**

The link in Peter's comment changed. Here is the [diagram](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/img/javaPluginTasks.png) from the [Gradle user's guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)

Comment: This is the correct answer. 'gradle assemble' will leave out many other tasks too. See this [diagram](http://gradle.org/latest/docs/userguide/userguide_single.html#N119C7) to get an idea. For typical real-life builds, 'gradle assemble' will leave out even more tasks.

Comment: Link from @PeterNiederwieser no longer valid. Probably he was referring to this diagram: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/img/javaPluginTasks.png

Comment: Works though you may need to add e.g. `-x integTest` and so on, so not as convenient as Maven’s blanket `-DskipTests`.

Comment: @c_maker, How to perform this from eclipse?

Comment: By the way, you can exclude not all, but the certain module's (i.e. for `module1`) tests using next syntax: `gradle build -x :module1:test`

Comment: As @PeterNiederwieser said, just don't call `gradle build`, but call the task you are interested in instead.

If all you care about is the artifacts of the project, `gradle assemble` would be appropriate.

Using `-x` is almost never necessary.

Comment: In my case I'm using the `artifactoryPublish` Gradle plugin and testing in a separate step. Tests kept failing only when the plugin executed and I don't want the publishing plugin to test code for me so this answer worked a treat. Thanks!

Comment: Based on your update, and on a multi-project grails app I'm working on, `-x check` worked where `-x test` did not.

Comment: `gradlew build -x integrationTest` in my case with an older gradle  (`2.9`) and groovy (`2.4.4`).

Answer (score 139):

Try:

```
gradle assemble
```

To list all available tasks for your project, try:

```
gradle tasks
```

UPDATE:

This may not seem the most correct answer at first, but read carefully `gradle tasks` output or docs.

```
Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assembles the outputs of this project.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
```

Comment: As an additional hint in case you are debugging your unit tests: `gradle assemble` will not compile the main files. If you work in getting your unit test fixed then  you need `gradle assemble testClasses` — I think that the build task naming is quite confusing.

Comment: I think that this answer should be the chosen one.

Answer (score 54):

You can add the following lines to `build.gradle`, `**/*` excludes all the tests.

```
test {
    exclude '**/*'
}
```

Comment: This is nice because I can do this in IntelliJ easy and not command line.

Comment: Unfortunately by doing this, it won't be possible to execute any test in IDEA.

Comment: @NikolaMihajlović you can wrap the exclude in an `if(....)` block ei. (in production only)

Comment: For Kotlin this needs to be inside **tasks** `test{
        exclude ("**/*")
    }`

Answer (score 43):

The accepted answer is the correct one.

OTOH, the way I previously solved this was to add the following to all projects:

```
test.onlyIf { ! Boolean.getBoolean('skip.tests') }
```

Run the build with `-Dskip.tests=true` and all test tasks will be skipped.

Comment: For me this is still the only working option as the -x test seems to only work on the starting project but not for dependencies in a multi project build (tested on gradle 2.1). Put the test.onlyif ... in a configure(subprojects.findAll {javaProjects.contains(it.name)}) {} block in your root build.gradle and it will work for all projects.

Answer (score 30):

Using `-x test` skip test execution but this also exclude test code compilation.

```
gradle build -x test
```

In our case, we have a CI/CD process where one goal is compilation and next goal is testing (Build -> Test).

So, for our first `Build` goal we wanted to ensure that the whole project compiles well. For this we have used:

```
./gradlew build testClasses -x test
```

On the next goal we simply execute tests:

```
./gradlew test
```

Comment: Does `./gradlew build testClasses -x test` just build testClasses? or does it build regular classes too? Do you need to run both `./gradlew build testClasses -x test` and `./gradlew build -x test`

Comment: @red888 The `build` builds regular ones while `testClasses` build test ones. You can check the different tasks here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

Answer (score 22):

Every action in gradle is a `task`, and so is `test`. And to exclude a `task` from gradle run, you can use the option `--exclude-task` or it's shorthand `-x` followed by the task name which needs to be excluded. Example:

```
gradle build -x test
```

The `-x` option should be repeated for all the tasks that needs to be excluded.

If you have different tasks for different type of tests in your `build.gradle` file, then you need to skip all those tasks that executes test. Say you have a task `test` which executes unit-tests and a task `testFunctional` which executes functional-tests. In this case, you can exclude all tests like below:

```
gradle build -x test -x testFunctional
```

Answer (score 10):

You can exclude tasks

```
 gradle build --exclude-task test
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_executing_tasks

Answer (score 7):

the different way to disable test tasks in the project is:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {enabled = false}
```

this behavior needed sometimes if you want to disable tests in one of a project(or the group of projects).

This way working for the all kind of test task, not just a java 'tests'. Also, this way is safe. Here's what I mean
  let's say: you have a set of projects in different languages:
  if we try to add this kind of record in main `build.gradle`:

```
 subprojects{
 .......
 tests.enabled=false
 .......
}
```

we will fail in a project when if we have no task called **tests**

Answer (score 5):

[Reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#excludeTask)

To exclude any task from gradle use `-x` command-line option. See the below example

```
task compile << {
    println 'task compile'
}

task compileTest(dependsOn: compile) << {
    println 'compile test'
}

task runningTest(dependsOn: compileTest) << {
    println 'running test'
}
task dist(dependsOn:[runningTest, compileTest, compile]) << {
    println 'running distribution job'
}
```

Output of: `gradle -q dist -x runningTest`

```
task compile
compile test
running distribution job
```

Hope this would give you the basic

Comment: please send a screen shot of the page. i dont know where to put this line of code....

Comment: This piece of code should go in your build.gradle :)

Answer (score 3):

In [The Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html):

```
$ gradle tasks

Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assembles the outputs of this project.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
testClasses - Assembles test classes.

Verification tasks
------------------
test - Runs the unit tests.
```

Gradle build without test you have two options:

```
$ gradle assemble
$ gradle build -x test
```

but if you want compile test:

```
$ gradle assemble testClasses
$ gradle testClasses
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.**kts**):

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> { // OR tasks.test {
    onlyIf {
        properties["areTestsEnabled"].toString().toBoolean()
    }
}
```

Execute the build like this:

```bash
./gradlew build
```

To include running tests:

```bash
./gradlew build -PareTestsEnabled=true
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

`gradlew -DskipTests=true build`

Comment: @KirankumarDafda - no. You can post an answer whenever you want, even if an existing answer had been accepted. The new answer might be better than the accepted answer, or solve it a different way, or otherwise help others. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23454025).

Comment: @WaiHaLee I cannot able to edit my comment, but as I got suggestions for new users, I wanted to explain that try to add answers with more clarifications so other user can check if why this answer or code is helpful to them.