# How can I not include a build task when I include a project in my settings.gradle file?

Tags: build, task, gradle

My `settings.gradle` file looks like:

```
include "serverTest", "shared"
```

And the serverTest `build.gradle` file looks like:

```
group = 'gradle'
version = '1.0'
defaultTasks 'build'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6

dependencies
{
  compile project(':shared')
}
```

The directory structure is: The top level holds the settings.gradle file and it has folders shared and serverTest in it.  Then in the serverTest directory there is the build.gradle file.

When I run gradle at the top level it outputs:

```
:shared:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:shared:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:shared:classes UP-TO-DATE
:shared:jar UP-TO-DATE
:serverTest:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:serverTest:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:serverTest:classes UP-TO-DATE
:serverTest:jar UP-TO-DATE
:serverTest:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:serverTest:compileTestJava
:serverTest:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:serverTest:testClasses
:serverTest:test
```

I don't want it to execute the task `:serverTest:test` though.  I tried changing my defaultTasks to just compileJava but that didn't work, does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: I assume you have also declared `defaultTasks` for the root project? From what I can tell, only the `defaultTasks` of the default project (which is determined based on the directory that Gradle is invoked from) are considered.

Comment: Do you always want to skip the `serverTest:test` task, or only sometimes?

Comment: @HieryNomus Always when I run it from the top level

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser but even if I did set the defaultTasks on the root project wouldn't it still execute the same tasks as it is now in the serverTest project?

Comment: Well, if you set `build` as the default, that certainly includes `test`. What *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make it so it doesn't run the serverTest:test task.  I need to build all the other directories, and I want to just compile the serverTest dir.

Comment: @Hiery Nomus Hey I haven't gotten a chance to check it out yet, can I put that in the settings.gradle file?

Comment: build.gradle of your root project...

Answer (score 6):

Well this question has been asked in different ways , the main theme of the question is;

**How to exclude sub tasks of build task?**

1 . **gradle build -x test**

The above instruction is helpful while executing gradle build command from CLI; this exludes test task, but we want to exclude test task programmatically in build.gradle file. Look below the answer for the respective question.

2 . **check.dependsOn -= test**

Copy this small script in your build.gradle file. 
Now when you execute **gradle build** from CLI, your tests won't run at all.

Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

You could try to disable the task only if a build task is present... Something like:

```
project(":serverTest").test.onlyIf { !gradle.taskGraph.hasTask(":shared:build") }
```