# Travis CI skip tests (Gradle Android project)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci

Now I'm configuring Travis CI for my Gradle-based Android project. Is it possible to temporary disable tests launch from Travis to just know - if project could be built or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, Travis-ci executes `./gradlew build connectedCheck` if no `script:` section is found.

Failed tests are ignored if you add the next code to all your tested modules (`build.gradle` files).

```
project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    connectedAndroidTest {
        ignoreFailures = true
    }
}
```

Another option is to skip the install stage and only to use `./gradlew build` (or `./gradle build` without gradle wrapper) so tests are not performed.

```
install:
  # Check install section: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#install
  # If you'd like to skip the install stage entirely, set it to true and nothing will be run.
  - true

script:
  # By default Travis-ci executes './gradlew build connectedCheck' if no 'script:' section found.
  - ./gradlew build
```

You can use the `-x` command line argument which excludes any task ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714118/1009132)).

```
gradle build -x test
```

Answer (score 0):

Check output of

```
./gradlew tasks
```

and then use:

```
./gradlew assemble
```

Like in this thread:
[Gradle build without tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597850/gradle-build-without-tests)

Comment: What about `./gradlew assemble test`.  Would that work?