# Equivalents for mvn update and mvn install in gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build-tools

I am new in gradle hence I have some questions about gradle. Before gradle I worked with maven and in maven there are some commands such as

- `mvn update`
- `mvn clean install`

With `mvn update` we download the dependency packages from internet and the other packages from the different projects.

With `mvn install` we create the *jar*, *war*, *ear* or *ejb*
so what are the equivalents for maven command in gradle?

- `mvn update` ~= `gradle ...`

  and
- `mvn clean install` ~= `gradle clean ...`

Comment: I don't know much about Maven, but Gradle specifically provides `jar` and `war` tasks if the corresponding plugins (`java` and `war` respectively) are declared in `build.gradle`

Comment: Have a look at this guide: https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-from-maven/

Answer (score 54):

Gradle will automatically fetch all required dependencies for you.

Long story short:

```
mvn update        ~= ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
mvn clean install ~= ./gradlew clean build
```

**TL;DR**

To force Gradle to redownload dependencies you can execute ([How can I force gradle to redownload dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31832995/5091346)):

```
./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
```

To assemble you project without executing tests ([Gradle build without tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597850/gradle-build-without-tests)):

```
./gradlew assemble
```

To completely build you project with test execution:

```
./gradlew build
```

You can skip certain tasks by providing `-x` argument:

```
./gradlew build -x test
```

Comment: The counterpart for maven's _install_ phase should be gradle's _install_ task (provided by the `maven` plugin) or the _publishToMavenLocal_ task (provided by the `maven-publish` plugin)

Answer (score 14):

The equivalent to

```
mvn clean install
```

is

```
gradle install
```

what is provided by the maven plug-in of Gradle. Just add the following line to your `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Comment: The other answer mentions `gradle build` as the equivalent: what is the difference?

Comment: `gradle build` doesn't put the resulting jar in a repository, it only builds it.

Comment: What is the gradle equivalent of `mvn clean -Dmaven.test.skip=true install`?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command:

```
./gradlew build
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44755949/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*