# How pass Gradle command parameters to execute a task through Buildship

Tags: gradle, spring-tool-suite, buildship, spring-tools-4

I know that if in Gradle I use: `build -x test` it builds and the test are not executed.

In STS with Buildship for support with Gradle, for example for Spring Integration

It has the following two tasks of my interest (*build* and *test*):

[image]

I can build with the following:

[image]

Because some test fails (randomly) I want skip the tests, so I tried

[image]

it fails with:

[image]

So I tried with:

[image]

And fails with

[image]

And with:

[image]

Nothing happens, only shows the following and stopping:

[image]

So how represent `build -x test` correctly with Buildship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must supply `-x test` as *Program Arguments* like this:

[image: Program Arguments configuration to exclude tests from Gradle build]

Or you just run [`assemble`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#lifecycle_tasks) instead of `build`. `assemble` is a lifecycle task that aggregates all archive tasks in the project and, besides other tasks, does not execute `check` tasks, such as `test`.

Comment: Thank you, let me test your approach. About `assemble`, is not correct, the correct approach is `build -x test`, please read the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714118/3665178