# How to pass arguments to Gradle task in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, build

For example, I would like to exclude tests from `build` here:

```
task foo(dependsOn: ['clean', 'build']) {
    build.mustRunAfter clean
}
```

Instead of `build` I need `build -x test`.
How can I pass `-x test` to `build` in Groovy?

Comment: Why not depend on something else instead of build?  Gradle doesn't work the way you're trying to use it...  If you only want compilation, then just depend on `assemble` https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#lifecycle_tasks

Comment: @tim_yates I need something that works exactly like `build` but without tests. `assemble` is different, see comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714118/5969852.

Comment: Is it javadoc or compiling the test classes you'd miss? Why compile them if you don't run them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start parameters like `-x` cannot be defined for single tasks. They are always part of a specific Gradle invocation.

You may however create a task that invokes Gradle from inside Gradle:

```
task foo(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = ['clean', 'build']
    startParameter.excludedTaskNames = ['test']
}
```