# Gradle equivalent of `mvn clean -Dmaven.test.skip=true install`

Tags: gradle

We know, the Gradle equivalent of `mvn clean install` is `gradle install`...

but what if I needed to install skipping all tests? In maven we would call:

```
mvn clean -Dmaven.test.skip=true install
```

What should we call in Gradle for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle build without tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597850/gradle-build-without-tests)

Comment: @omajid Let me try... Build differs from install, as the latter one installs jar to the repo... But the provided command-line options should also work for install.

Answer (score -1):

```
./gradlew install -x test
```

Using `-x test` skips both: test execution and test code compilation.